# how to Read a .xml file from Resources.resx?

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, dataset

I have added a `.xml` file to application resources.
Now I want to access that xml file and fill dataset using that xml file in c#.net

Can anyone help that how can i do this in `C#.net`

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy. Let's assume you have a file named `YourXml` in your `resources.resx`:

```
// creating XDocument from your file
var xml = XDocument.Parse(Resources.YourXml);
// creating an empty DataSet object
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
// filling DataSet with the xml read
dataSet.ReadXml(xml.CreateReader());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the resource file, an xml is actually a string. You can try `XDocument.Parse(Resources.YourResourceName, LoadOptions.None)` to parse your xml string. Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Howard

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, it's not added to the dataset, just binding to a listbox;

1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Resources>
  <R>A</R>
  <R>B</R>
  <R>C</R>
</Resources>
```

c# code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(WpfApplication1.Properties.Resources._1, LoadOptions.None);
            var itemsSource = doc.Descendants("R");
            List1.ItemsSource = itemsSource;
```

XAML code

```
<ListBox x:Name="List1" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```